# How do you remove `this` keyword from method in factory function?

Tags: javascript, this

**My Question**
In the simple factory function below I used `this` in the totalCost method to reference its parent object.  How could I build something like this without using `this`?  I can't see what pattern to use.

```js
"use strict"

function planeCreator(a, b, c) {
    return {
        manufacturer: a,
        numberOfEngines: b,
        costPerEngine: c,
        totalCost: function() {
            return this.numberOfEngines * this.costPerEngine;
        }
    }
}

let b17 = planeCreator('B-17', 4, 25000);

document.querySelectorAll('.output')[0].textContent = b17.totalCost();
```

```html
<div class='output'></div>
```

**Backstory**
The more I read about Javascript the more I find criticisms of `Constructor` functions and the `new` and `this` keywords.  In [The Two Pillars of JavaScript](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3) by Eric Elliott he cautions programmers against using Constructors and mentions that Douglas Crockford never uses `new` or `this`.

My problem is that although its easy enough to avoid Constructors and the new keyword I'm not quite sure how to avoid `this`.  What pattern would I replace it with?

Comment: but why you want to avoid `this`, `this` is just an intrinsic part of javascript

Comment: That's super old advice that is no longer relevant. Douglas Crockford himself have changed his mind about how to do OO in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the newly created object to a variable, and reference that variable:

(also note that if you're just selecting a single element, better to use `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll`)

```js
function planeCreator(a, b, c) {
  const objToReturn = {
    manufacturer: a,
    numberOfEngines: b,
    costPerEngine: c,
    totalCost: () => objToReturn.numberOfEngines * objToReturn.costPerEngine,
  };
  return objToReturn;
}

const b17 = planeCreator('B-17', 4, 25000);

document.querySelector('.output').textContent = b17.totalCost();
```

```html
<div class='output'></div>
```

Personally, I don't think there's anything wrong with using the Class keyword and `this` - less syntax noise is good, and like all language constructs, you simply have to learn how to use it properly. It's true you should avoid`this` when you don't need it, but you shouldn't go much *out of your way* to avoid using it, I think. Similarly, ES6's `.reduce` might be confusing to newcomers too, but once you understand how to use it properly, go ahead and use it. It's terse and powerful.